# how to visualise hadoop interface installed in ubuntu server in a remote windows machine

Tags: hadoop, networking, remote-server, ubuntu-server

I have installed hadoop in Ubuntu server ,and I want to visualise the hadoop interface in a windows machine using the browser.
the two machines are in the same network.

I've tried in the browser :

```
@IP:8088
and
@IP:9001
```

I know i'm missing something, i need your help . 
thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for anyone searching , 
you need to add this to C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

under localhost :
@ip of ubuntu server     name_server

in your browser you specify :
http://name_server:8088

Good luck